SwiftUI Handling EnvironmentObject Resets with navigationLink : Avoiding Navigation View Rebuilds
I have the code below where I use a NavigationLink to add multiple child views on button click. However, as soon as I increase the EnvironmentObject value, all views reset, and only ChildView 1 remains.

@main
struct NavigationResetIssueApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(Observer())
        }
    }
}

enum Route {
    case child
}

class Observer: ObservableObject {
    @Published var observedValue: Int = 0
    init() {
        print("Observer init")
    }
}
struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var observer: Observer
    @State var navigateToRoute: Route?
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Text("Current observer Value: \(observer.observedValue)")
                    .font(.headline)
                    .padding()
                
                Button("Move to Child View") {
                    navigateToRoute = .child
                }
                .padding()
                
                NavigationLink(destination:  ChildView(num: 1)                    ,
                               tag: Route.child,
                               selection: $navigateToRoute,
                               label: { })
            }
        }
    }
}


struct ChildView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var observer: Observer
    @State var viewNum:Int
    @State var navigateToRoute: Route?
    init(num:Int) {
        self.viewNum = num
        print("initializing ChildView")
    }
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            let _ = print("chilChildViewd body")
            Text("observer Value: \(observer.observedValue)")
                .font(.headline)
                .padding()
            Button("Incrtease Observer Value") {
                observer.observedValue += 1
            }
            .padding()
            
            Button("Move to Next Child View") {
                navigateToRoute = .child
            }
            .padding()
            
            NavigationLink(destination: ChildView(num: self.viewNum+1) ,
                           tag: Route.child,
                           selection: $navigateToRoute,
                           label: { })
        }
        .navigationTitle("ChildView # \(viewNum)")
    }
}

In another place, I removed the use of EnvironmentObject in the ChildView controller and changed the EnvironmentObject value after 5 seconds in the content view. Again, all child views reset, and only the first child view remains. Here is the updated code:
struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var observer: Observer
    @State var navigateToRoute: Route?
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Text("Current observer Value: \(observer.observedValue)")
                    .font(.headline)
                    .padding()
                
                Button("Move to Child View") {
                    navigateToRoute = .child
                }
                .padding()
                
                NavigationLink(destination:  ChildView(num: 1)                    ,
                               tag: Route.child,
                               selection: $navigateToRoute,
                               label: { })
            }
        }.onAppear(perform: {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 10, execute: {
                print("------- ContentView After 5 sec -------")
                observer.observedValue = 50
            })
        })
    }
}


struct ChildView: View {
    @State var viewNum:Int
    @State var navigateToRoute: Route?
    init(num:Int) {
        self.viewNum = num
        print("initializing ChildView")
    }
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            let _ = print("chilChildViewd body")
             Button("Move to Next Child View") {
                navigateToRoute = .child
            }
            .padding()
            
            NavigationLink(destination: ChildView(num: self.viewNum+1) ,
                           tag: Route.child,
                           selection: $navigateToRoute,
                           label: { })
        }
        .navigationTitle("ChildView # \(viewNum)")
    }
}

Kindly let me know how to prevent this behavior.
Thank you so much for your attention and participation.

you need to learn state and binding instead of objects

@malhal
Thank you for the suggestion. I appreciate your perspective and will look into learning more about state and binding. Could you please suggest fix for above issue.

In addition to moving the Observer out to a @State var I think you got the navigation all mixed up. Try the NavigationStack it is far more simple.
e.g.:
struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var observer: Observer
    // here we store the navigation
    @State var path: [Int] = []
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $path) {
            VStack {
                Text("Current observer Value: \(observer.observedValue)")
                    .font(.headline)
                    .padding()
                
                Button("Move to Child View") {
                    path.append(1)
                }
                .navigationDestination(for: Int.self, destination: { num in
                    // the value appended to path will appear here as num
                    // pass the path on as binding, so we can manipulate it from the childview
                    ChildView(num: num, path: $path)
                        .environmentObject(observer)
                })
                .padding()
            }
        }
    }
}


struct ChildView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var observer: Observer
    @Binding var path: [Int]
    // no state needed here
    var viewNum: Int
    
    init(num: Int, path: Binding<[Int]>) {
        self.viewNum = num
        self._path = path
        print("initializing ChildView")
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            let _ = print("chilChildViewd body")
            Text("observer Value: \(observer.observedValue)")
                .font(.headline)
                .padding()
            Button("Incrtease Observer Value") {
                observer.observedValue += 1
            }
            .padding()
            
            Button("Move to Next Child View") {
                // increase the num that gets passed to the next child
                path.append(viewNum + 1)
            }
            .padding()
        }
        .navigationTitle("ChildView # \(viewNum)")
    }
}


Edit:
You never mentioned this being below IOS 16, but if you really want, or need to use NavigationViewtry the example below. Tested on Xcode 15.4 and IOS 15 as target.
struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject private var observer: Observer
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            VStack {
                Text("Current observer Value: \(observer.observedValue)")
                    .font(.headline)
                    .padding()
                
                NavigationLink {
                    ChildView(num: 1)
                } label: {
                    Text("Move to Child View")
                }

            }
        }
    }
}


struct ChildView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject private var observer: Observer
    var viewNum: Int
    
    init(num: Int) {
        self.viewNum = num
        print("initializing ChildView")
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            let _ = print("chilChildViewd body")
            Text("observer Value: \(observer.observedValue)")
                .font(.headline)
                .padding()
            Button("Incrtease Observer Value") {
                observer.observedValue += 1
            }
            .padding()
            
            NavigationLink {
                ChildView(num: viewNum + 1)
            } label: {
                Text("Move to Next Child View")
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("ChildView # \(viewNum)")
    }
}


Thank you so much. It's working well now. Is there any other way to achieve it under iOS 16, as NavigationStack does not work in that scenario?

Many thanks. It's working well now.

Try this approach using @StateObject private var observer = Observer() to let
the View/App observe and manage the model. Note also, NavigationView is deprecated use NavigationStack
instead.
@main
struct NavigationResetIssueApp: App {
    @StateObject private var observer = Observer() // <--- here
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(observer)  // <--- here
        }
    }
}

Have a look at this Apple link  Monitoring data it gives you some good examples of how to manage data in your app.

Thanks for your quick response and the video link. I will check that out. Unfortunately, with the above changes, I am still getting the older behavior.
